# Creating an app for an already made website

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, xcode6, mobile-application

I just started an internship for my local county and the first task I got from them was to create an app for their already existing job searching/posting site(like monster.com or jobfind, etc). I never made an app before as my school didn't offer an ios development course so I am kind of stressing out over this and have pretty much been left to figure it out myself.

I am doing well on the ui design for the app and its turning out nicely. The issue i am having is for the registration forms and postings. For example, when registering for an account I have a registration form filled with labels and text fields like so:

Name:  _____________
Phone:  _____________ 
Address: ____________

And so on. So my question is, how do I get what the user inputs in the text fields when registering/logging into the app to actually connect to the same database the already running website is connected to. I have access to the php folder/files to the website and also the database on mysql workbench. I have viewed numerous tutorials and read a few of them but they use different examples than mine and ended up confusing me more. I figured I would post a question here in case anyone has done this before or maybe has read/seen a great tutorial that I have not came across yet. Any help/tips would be extremely appreciated as I would like to learn how to do so. I am using objective-c and xcode 6. Thank you

Comment: The first thing to think about is how the web server will present an "API" to the data it holds.  This can be done multiple ways (think how Google expose their stuff to client apps via web-based APIs).  If the site doesn't currently do this then the task will involve more than just creating a client.

Comment: You need to build an API

Comment: How do i build an api? Does it have to be made for the site and the app? I guess what I mean is, do I have to create a api php file for the site and then an api class for xcode?